# Trouble integrating POIJI into my project

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to read and convert an Excel file into Java objects, but i can't seem to compile, as there is an error when i try to create the List.

I've imported the POIJI .jar file, and have successfully implemented it in the Java object side of things. I have trouble with the FileInputStream. The variable options is unable to be resolved.

I tried looking at the github instructions, but there's nothing regarding this.

Error message: "options cannot be resolved to a variable"

I've imported the following:

```
import com.poiji.bind.Poiji;
import com.poiji.exception.PoijiExcelType;
import com.poiji.annotation.*;
import com.poiji.option.PoijiOptions;
import com.poiji.option.PoijiOptions.PoijiOptionsBuilder;


    public void readExcel(String filePath) {
        
        try {

            InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            PoijiOptions options = PoijiOptionsBuilder.settings().headerStart(1).build();
            List<VehicleData> vehicleDataList = Poiji.fromExcel(stream, PoijiExcelType.XLS, VehicleData.class, options);        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should pass the `options` object as a parameter to your method.

Comment: @Arnaud, i tried creating the options as a variable right, but then eclipse tells me that .headerStart() is not defined. what am i doing wrong?